# Comments on SQL equality check "length(col) = length (?) and col = ?"

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

A previous developer has all of their `Select * from TABLE where COLUMN = value;` with an additional check so that the where clause is `length(COLUMN) = length(value) and COLUMN = value` when performing equality checks on String-type columns.

The reasoning (as I understand) is that performing the length check can be faster and therefore improve the performance of these types of queries. My feelings are

- if concerned, why not use an index on the DB? (I haven't checked, but these may already be there)
- is it likely to improve the query at all, and if at all would it be specific to a certain engine or DB version?
- can it in fact be worse?
- if this is that much better, wouldn't the DB engine be likely to perform its own check under the covers? (eg statement compilation and optimisations)
- under what conditions would anyone actually notice the change?
- does it result in some either (positive or negative) DB type side effect?

I believe it was initially targeting MySQL 5.1 and we're now on MySQL 5.7, but my *request for comments* is not specific to these. My Google-foo returned nothing on the topic, but it smells like premature optimisation.

Note also that these are only used for direct equality, typically on unique fields, often on small tables and also often for enumeration of lookup type tables.

Comment: I cant really offer any insight as to wether that's going to work. What I'd note is that performing calculations on a column in view of filtering is broadly not recommended year(date col) = {year} isn't as efficient as 'date col > {parameter} and datecol < {parameter} I'd seriously doubt that even if the Len() filters do help at all that they are the most important optimisation.

Comment: I am 100% certain that this wouldn't make a difference for any modern optimizer (Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server). Although highly unlikely, **if** there is a difference, I would expect the one with the additional condition to be slower (but again: I highly doubt it). MySQL's optimizer is less efficient than the others, so I don't know if this is true for MySQL as well

Comment: Note that `length('ab  ')` = 4, and `length('ab')` = 2, but still `'ab  ' = 'ab'`...

Comment: Comparing lengths is not significantly faster than comparing strings -- Fetching the rows is the costly part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this handles spaces at the end of a string.

As you can see in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=813314e4fe4182bcfe4856d27e0d3628):

```
select ('abc' = 'abc '), length('abc'), length('abc ')
```

MySQL does not (in the versions you mention) support check constraints.  So there is no simple way to prevent spaces from the end of strings.

In general, such spaces would be examples of bad data.  My guess is that the developer encountered this problem once upon a time and inserted these checks as defensive programming.

I *think* I would instead recommend using `BINARY` to get an exact match:

```
('abc' = binary 'abc ')
```

I'm not sure if this would have some unexpected consequences.